# Click on an IE button whose source code only states class and href

Tags: vba

I've managed to write the correct code in VBA to open up a particular website. I now want to write the correct code that will result in clicking on a particular button on that website.

I'm really struggling to paste the code of the element which is the button I want my VBA code to click on. But it's the last `"Get a quote"` button on a site and it's just below the following text: _"You're in good hands"

And the other part of the problem is that there is another similar button on this page, with the following source code:

```
</div>
    <div class="SelfService-quote">

            <div class="SelfService-quoteBtn">
<button class="sg-Btn sg-Btn--primary">GET a QUOTE for <span
        class="Icon-arrowBottom--light Icon--xsmall SelfService-btnArrow"></span>
</button>
</div>
```

So what I need to do is to be able to automate the clicking on the correct button. If someone could provide me with the VBA code for that, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button you're wanting to click isn't really a button. It's just a link (`<a>`) masquerading as a button.

```
<a class="sg-Btn sg-Btn--primary" href="/secure/comprehensive-car-insurance-get-a-quote.html">
    <span>Get a quote</span>
</a>
```

So there's really no need to go through the trouble of "clicking" it. Just navigate to the URL:

```
ie.Navigate "https://www.aami.com.au/secure/comprehensive-car-insurance-get-a-quote.html"
```

If you do want to "click" it, however, you can use `GetElementsByClassName()` to return an array of DOM elements matching that class. It will return two elements. The link/button you want to click is the second element (array index `1`):

```
Dim e
Set e = ie.Document.GetElementsByClassName("sg-Btn sg-Btn--primary")(1)
e.Click
```

Comment: Thanks very much Bond! I'm such a complete novice at this stuff, but I'm hoping to learn by trial and error and asking around

Answer (score 0):

@Bond is correct. Neither "Get a quote" element is really a button (vote his answer up, not mine). The first produces a drop down box of links like this:

```
<ul class="SelfService-quoteList sg-List-unstyled">
    <li class="SelfService-quoteItem"><a href="/secure/comprehensive-car-insurance-get-a-quote.html" target="_self" class=" ">Car Insurance</a></li>
    <li class="SelfService-quoteItem"><a href="/secure/home-insurance-get-a-quote.html" target="_self" class=" ">Home & Contents</a></li>
    <li class="SelfService-quoteItem"><a href="/secure/renters-fire-theft-get-a-quote.html" target="_self" class=" ">Renters Fire & Theft</a></li>
    <li class="SelfService-quoteItem"><a href="/secure/landlord-home-get-a-quote.html" target="_self" class=" ">Landlord Insurance</a></li>
    <li class="SelfService-quoteItem"><a href="/secure/travel-insurance-get-a-quote.html" target="_self" class=" ">Travel Insurance</a></li>
    <li class="SelfService-quoteItem"><a href="/motorcycle-insurance.html" target="_self" class=" ">Motorcycle Insurance</a></li>
    <li class="SelfService-quoteItem"><a href="/secure/nsw-ctp-get-a-quote.html" target="_self" class=" ">CTP Greenslip - NSW</a></li>
    <li class="SelfService-quoteItem"><a href="/life-insurance/quotes.html" target="_self" class=" ">Life Insurance</a></li>
    <li class="SelfService-quoteItem"><a href="/life-insurance/income-protection.html" target="_self" class=" ">Income Protection</a></li>
    <li class="SelfService-quoteItem"><a href="/secure/business-insurance-quote.html" target="_self" class=" ">Business Insurance</a></li>
</ul>
```

The second (which appears to be the one you want to "click" is (from @Bond's post):

```
<a class="sg-Btn sg-Btn--primary" href="/secure/comprehensive-car-insurance-get-a-quote.html">
    <span>Get a quote</span>
</a>
```

Simply navigate to the page you wish to go to rather than clicking any element on the homepage.

For that matter, you could even build your own form and then post the data to the server yourself. This would only require you to load one page: the results page.